# How much transfer time for domestic flight arriving in LGA, transferring to JFK for an International Flight?

Tags: air-travel, planning, airlines, jfk, lga

I am planning a flight from Atlanta, Georgia to Manila, departing Monday, March 13th.

I want to catch the flight to Manila at 11:54 am out of JFK.

The earliest flight i could find getting into jfk from atl arrives at 10:27am.  Is that cutting it too close?

The other option is to fly into LGA.  There is a flight that arrives in LGA by 8:10 am.  Is that  enough time to go by taxi from LGA to JFK and arrive at JFK by around 10 am on a monday morning?

If I buy the ticket, does that mean the carrier(s) have left enought time for the transfer?

Comment: Would this all be on one ticket, or across two different tickets? If you're delayed and missed the onward flight, how long will you have to wait for the next one? And what's the on-time performance like for your 1st flight?

Comment: Assuming the JFK-MNL flight is on Philippine Airlines, even if you are booked on a single ticket from ATL (and have any bags checked all the way through to MNL), the connection would be extremely tight. PAL flies out of Terminal 1, which is not connected airside to any other terminal. Thus, you will need to exit whichever terminal your domestic flight arrives at (presumably Delta, T2 or T4), walk or take the AirTrain (Howard Beach or Jamaica lines) to T1, then clear security again.

Comment: On what day of the week?

Comment: @karlson  On a Monday morning.

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC on Monday morning and with construction on vanWick it may be just enough time.

Comment: @choster that looks suspiciously like an answer. ;)

Comment: @CGCampbell Well, the meat of the question is about an LGA-JFK transfer, something I have no direct experience with. If no one else can answer, I'll try to write something up in a few hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10:27am to 11:54am is insanely tight. The domestic to international MCT at JFK is 1:15 so I think the booking is possible but JFK is notorious for issuing impossible MCTs (at one point United was selling a ticket with a transfer time of 30 minutes to a different terminal!). So you are a full 12 minutes above the official unrealistic MCT. Nope.

You land at LGA at 8:10AM, let's say you clear that airport in 40 minutes, that's 8:50AM, the drive over should not be more than 40 minutes but even if it's 60 you have two hours to go through JFK check-in and security. This is way more realistic.

Comment: I am not sure whether 40-60 minutes still stand when you are talking about 8-9 am on a Monday.  Monday rush hour traffic is notoriously bad.  However there should still be enough time, hopefully, to catch the flight from JFK, especially if you can check in online.