# LGA/JFK connections for trip to Moscow

Tags: transit, jfk, lga

I have a trip next month to Moscow. I am flying to LGA and have 2.5 hours to switch to JFK before my departure on Aeroflot to Moscow. Is that enough time to switch airports?

Comment: Is it during rush hour?

Comment: Is the flight to LGA international? Do you have checked baggage?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan As far as I know, the only international arrivals at LGA are pre-cleared, so the OP should not need to go through immigration and customs.

Comment: Also see *[Would 3 hours be an ok transfer time from LGA to JFK for international flight?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89000)* and *[How much transfer time for domestic flight arriving in LGA, transferring to JFK for an International Flight?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43889)* among others.